# Cannot Invoke setMetadataObjectsDelegate with an argument list of type (CustomVC, queue:dispatch_queue_t!)

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

It doesn't like the arguments that I'm putting into setMetadataObjectsDelegate. Here's the code, which I've put in my UIViewController subclass under viewdidload

```
captureMetadataOutput.metadataObjectsDelegate
captureMetadataOutput.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue:  dispatch_get_main_queue())
captureMetadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = [AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode]
captureSession?.addOutput(captureMetadataOutput)
```

My suspicion is that the problem is more likely with my use of 'self' than dispatch_get_main_queue(), but I don't know. This code seems like it's worked for other people.

Comment: How have you defined your `CustomVC` class?  Does it inherit from the appropriate delegate protocol class? i.e. `AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate`

Comment: I almost literally face-palmed when I read that and realized. That was the problem. Thank you